# how to use a single sqlcmd session in a Bash script

Tags: bash

This Bash script executes each file in the `files` array on the database.  However, it creates a new sqlcmd session for each file.  Is there a way to create a single sqlcmd session before the loop and then use that session for all file executions?

```
#!/bin/bash

# declare and initialize an array of files to be executed (listed in sequence of execution)
declare -a files=(
    '0140_Items.sql'
    '0170_Warehouses.sql'
    '0190_ItemsAtWarehouses.sql'
)

# loop through files array to execute each file on database
for file in "${files[@]}"
do
   sqlcmd -S SQLDEV14 -E -d D7stage -i ".\Modules\\$file" -m 1
done
```

If so, what is the syntax?  I have searched blogs and forums for how to do this but have not found anything that's helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
# loop through files array and build a string of comma separated input files in variable called inputFiles
for file in "${files[@]}"
do
   inputFiles+=".\Modules\\$file"
done
# echo $inputFiles

# execute multiple input files on database using one sqlcmd session
sqlcmd -S SQLDEV14 -E -d D7stage -i $inputFiles -m 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a shell such as `bash` you could concatenate the files and pipe them in as a single entity:

```
sqlcmd -S SQLDEV14 -E -d D7stage -i <(cd Modules && cat "${files[@]}") -m 1
```

Comment: This looks promising.  How do I prepend the `".\Modules\\"` for each file though?

Comment: @knot22 You can use bash parameter expansion, like this: `<(cat "${files[@]/#/.\\Modules\\\\}")`

Comment: @knot22 there you go